# From a java program, launch a Python script which listens for socket connections from said Java program

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

Im attempting to launch a python script from my Java program - The python script listens for socket connections from the Java program and responds with data.
In order to do this I have attempted to use the ProcessBuilder API to:

1. activate a python virtualenv (located in my working directory)
2. run my python script predictprobability.py such that it starts listening for connections from my java program.
   this is what I have so far:

```
public class MLClassifierProcess{
                                                //bash location        //activate python venv  //python interpreter      //script
    final String[] command_to_run = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "/env/bin/activate;", "/env/bin/python","predictprobability.py;" };
    public void startML(){
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command_to_run);
        Process pr = null;

        try {
            pr = builder.start();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MLClassifierProcess p = new MLClassifierProcess();
        p.startML();
    }

}
```

however running the main function terminates straight away, when the script predictprobability.py should continue to run indefinitely.
I'm new to the ProcessBuilder API so any pointers on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If your Java program exits, the Python process you launched will exit as well as child processes are killed when a parent process dies unless they have been detached from that process.

If you want your Java program to keep running until the Python program has completed execution, then you need to have the Java code wait appropriately.  Here's how to have it do so:

```
public class MLClassifierProcess{
    //bash location        //activate python venv  //python interpreter      //script
    final String[] command_to_run = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "/env/bin/activate;", "/env/bin/python","predictprobability.py;" };
    public Process startML(){
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command_to_run);
        Process pr = null;

        try {
            pr = builder.start();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return pr;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MLClassifierProcess p = new MLClassifierProcess();
        Process pr = p.startML();
        if (pr != null)
            pr.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, however running that code produces a null value for pr - would this suggest that my command_to_run is not formed properly so my script is not being executed?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the execution is failing.  According to the docs, `builder.start()` is unable to return a `null` value.  So it must be throwing an exception.  Your code would catch that exception and print "error".  Is it doing that?  If so, you should have it print the exception so that you can see what the error is that you're getting.  Optionally, you can stop inside the `catch` in your debugger and check out the exception that way.

Comment: A few specific things I see: 1) is your virtual environment really in a directory named `env` at the root of your filesystem?  2) Are you sure that your python script is in the current working directory such that it will be found by Python with no path component.  You can eliminate the second concern by supplying the full path of your script.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was simple:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<path/to/venv/python_interpreter> "+"path/to/scripytorun.py)
```

In my case the succcessful command was

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/env/bin/python "+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/predictprobability.py");
process.waitFor();
```

@CryptoFool was right to point out that the absolute path to resources is needed, hence the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` prepended to the relative paths

Comment: Do you have any arguments for your .py program? when you have arguments, does it still work?